# Definition of symmetric product in Milnor's paper

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds

I am currently reading [Milnor's paper](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2372566?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) which discusses the group action on spheres without fixed point. At the second page of the paper, he denotes $$M^n*M^n$$ to be a **symmetric product** of a manifold. I was confused of what this means, as it does not adjust to any of the definition of the terms on Wikipedia.
Any comments in appreciated.

Comment: It should mean $M*M = M\times M/ \sim$, where $(x, y) \sim (y, x)$.

Comment: Is it perhaps the [join](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28topology%29)?

Comment: I think John's answer should be the original intention. The rest parts says we can 'trivialise' $f_1$, which hence the join does not make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It should mean $M*M = M\times M/ \sim$, where $(x, y) \sim (y, x)$. -- [John Ma](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1522372/definition-of-symmetric-product-in-milnors-paper#comment3100026_1522372)

To confirm that the answer by John Ma is correct, I looked up [another paper](http://www.math.utah.edu/~keenan/actions.pdf) which gives this definition of symmetric product just before citing the aforementioned Milnor's paper about it.